# Display UserControl in devexpress Gridview when user expands a row

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Is it possible to display a usercontrol in Devexpress gridview when a user expands a row?

Comment: Any example code you want to provide? It may possible but without a sample it's hard to see what you need.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q530046/how-to-show-usercontrol-within-a-grid-cell

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding a UserControl into a cell may be a quite difficult task. Consider using [Custom Edit Form](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/16215/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing/Edit-Form/Custom-Edit-Form).